# How can I use NFC to send arbitrary data to another phone?

Tags: 8.0, nfc

I've found various apps that allow you to write data to NFC tags, and I know the phone has built-in features for sharing some things directly to other phones (e.g.: pictures, apps) via a combination NFC/Bluetooth connection. However, I'm interested in finding a way to send arbitrary data (e.g.: text, URLs, etc) directly from one phone to another using NFC only.

Is this possible via built-in functions that I just haven't found yet, or is there an app required?

Comment: What you mean with arbitrary? You mean open a textbox, type something and send via NFC? I know you can share links in the browser, apps in the context menu an app.

Comment: @VitorCanova Exactly that - I want to just send a text message (e.g.: containing a WiFi PSK) from one device to another without actually having to make & send a file.

Comment: There is functionality to allow direct device to device NFC sharing. Are you looking for an existing app that will allow you to type or retrieve some text and then use the tap + send feature to send to another phone?  Right now receiving text via NFC is built in, but sharing any random text would require an app.

Comment: @caschw That's pretty much what I'm looking for. I'd like to know if there's an app that comes pre-loaded with the OS (or with Lumia 920s particularly) that allows you to send arbitrary text strings via NFC-only connections. Alternately, third-party apps that do the job would be interesting as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested with NFC tags, however Windows Phone handles NFC tags and NFC communication between two devices identically. Using [NFC Tag Writer](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/nfc-tag-writer/895711f1-2b38-4af1-8780-f6501f4371e0), I can write a plain text tag.

When Windows Phone receives a properly formatted NFC plain text message (from device or tag) it will prompt for action.

[image]

And if you allow it, open plain text in the built in Word app.

[image]

To send this using tap and send, an app would have to format the tag in the same way NFC Tag Writer does for plain text, but no additional steps have to be done to open it in Word.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there aren't any built in functionality to send this kind of information.

Want you have is some options to send data via Tap+Send when available at share option.

Third-part apps usually focus on read data from a tag or write data to it, but you can search for "NFC publisher".

I tried 2 apps but looks like they are limited by an app that must understand the protocol you are using. Tried NFC Comm and NFC Publisher. Both can send text to an NFC device but you need a place is this device to handle the data.

Comment: In the NFC spec there is capability to send raw strings. The windows phone does know how to handle these raw strings.

Comment: One of those apps has an option to send binary data. I can type a lot of text. When I sent this data the other phone made the sound it does when are receiving NFC data but it does nothing after that.